# Best way to read many files with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large glob of file paths. I'm getting this path list from a streaming glob module https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream

I was piping this stream to another stream that was creating `fileReadStreams` for each path and quickly hitting some limits. I was getting the:

`warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

and also `Error: EMFILE, open`

I've tried bumping the `maxListeners` but I have ~9000 files that would be creating streams and I'm concerned that will eat memory that number is not constant and will grow. Am I safe to remove the limit here?

Should I be doing this synchronously? or should I be iterating over the paths and reading the files sequentially? Won't that still execute all the reads at once using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max listeners thing is [purely a warning](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/lib/events.js#L152-162).  [`setMaxListeners`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) only controls when that message is printed to the console, nothing else.  You can disable it or just ignore it.

The `EMFILE` is your OS enforcing a limit on the number of open files (file descriptors) your process can have at a single time.  You could avoid this by [increasing the limit with ulimit](http://blog.izs.me/post/56827866110/wtf-is-emfile-and-why-does-it-happen-to-me).

Because saturating the disk by running many thousands of concurrent filesystem operations won't get you any added performance—in fact, it will hurt, especially on traditional non-SSD drives—it is a good idea to only run a controlled number of operations at once.

I'd probably use an [async queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), which allows you to push the name of every file to the queue in one loop, and then only runs *n* operations at once.  When an operation finishes, the next one in the queue starts.

For example:

```
var q = async.queue(function (file, cb) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    // ...
    stream.on('end', function() {
        // finish up, then
        cb();
    });
}, 2);

globStream.on('data', function(file) {
    q.push(file);
});

globStream.on('end', function() {
    // We don't want to add the `drain` handler until *after* the globstream
    // finishes.  Otherwise, we could end up in a situation where the globber
    // is still running but all pending file read operations have finished.
    q.drain = function() {
        // All done with everything.
    };

    // ...and if the queue is empty when the globber finishes, make sure the done
    // callback gets called.
    if (q.idle()) q.drain();
});
```

You may have to experiment a little to find the right concurrency number for your application.

Comment: @kevzettler: Since your test never actually consumes data, [the docs say the `end` event will not fire](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end).